# how to pass data from view to controller using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

From my view I can upload the file when the user clicks upload, the file should then call ajax and pass that file name to my controller. The controller will then perform its steps.

view.php :

```
 <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="myform">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Select file</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="file" name="file" type="file">
                                        <input type="submit" class="blue btn" value="Add" id="submitbutton">

                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <a href="">Or add single user</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>          


                            </form>
```

Script :

```
 <script>   
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#submitbutton").click(function(e) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/admin_user_controller/addtodb/',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                            success: function() {
                                alert("success");
                                $('#file').val('');

                            },
                            error: function() {
                                alert("Fail");
                            }
                        });
                        e.preventDefault(); // could also use: return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Controller :

```
 public function addtodb() {

        $name=$this->input->post('file');
        echo $name;
        $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo $uploadfile;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {
            $handle = fopen("$uploadfile", "r");
            $no = 0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                $temp[$no] = $data[0];
                $no++;
            }
            $this->load->model('admin_user_model');
            $flag = $this->admin_user_model->insertrecord($temp, $name);
            echo $flag;
            if ($flag) {
                $this->load->view('admin_user_view');
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        echo "done";
    }
```

Comment: How far have you debugged ?

Comment: no i havent debugg the code

Comment: Are you getting value within your `controller` function

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs?

Comment: use this jquery plugin for submit images or post data, http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Comment: still its not working